# Redirect a URL and remove a segment

Tags: redirects, template-routes

I recently redid an ExpressionEngine site that was not using template routes for a blog, so the blog URLs were like this: http://mywebsite/blog/detail/url-title-here

After the redesign, I created a template route and removed the 'detail' segment changing the URLs like this: http://mywebsite/blog/url-title-here

Both URLs are now accessible though, so I want to redirect all of the old URLs to the new ones without 'detail' in the URL.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just figured it out with an htaccess RewriteRule.

RewriteRule ^blog/detail(.*)$ /blog$1 [NC,R=301,L]